# Every set is open in well ordered set?

Tags: general-topology, well-orders

Book i am following is Munkres.Suppose $X$ is well ordered set. Since every set contains smallest element , suppose i take any set of the form , say $(a,b)$ then consider set $(b,c)$ where $c>b$ .Since every set contains smallest element , let the smallest element in $(b,c)$ be $y$ .Hence $y$ is immediate successor of $b$ .Thus using this argument , every element in $X$ has immediate successor and predecessor .Thus if i take any set of the form say $(a,b)$ then it is closed automatically (by definition of order topology). Suppose i take any set of the form $[a,b)$ then it is also open since $[a,b) = (d,b)$ where $d$ is immediate predecessor of $a$ .

Thus by above argument we can say all intervals (open,half closed,closed) are open and closed in well ordered set .

Obviously i didn't proved for any arbitrary set and thus i am asking this question .

Edit : One more observation , every point set is open in $X$ .Suppose $x ∈ X$, then let $y$ be immediate predecessor of x , take interval $(y,x]$ , hence it is open by above argument .Is this observation correct ?

Comment: @JackCrawford According to Munkres a set is called well ordered if every subset of $A$ has smallest element . I think by this definition my approach is correct  .

Comment: @JackCrawford According to definition of order topology , sets of the form $(d,b)$ are indeed open .That's why i mentioned Munkres in beginning , since i am reading from that book .

Comment: @JackCrawford According to Munkres , interval notation has meaning for the example you are giving . $(0,3)$ = {1,2}

Comment: @JackCrawford $(0,3)$ is open in order topology

Comment: Ah, I was incorrect and retract my previous comments: I'm sorry for wasting any of your time. It turns out I was just unfamiliar with the order topology and was thinking in terms of us having placed a well-order on a different topology.

Comment: @JackCrawford Well you should not delete comments since people having similar doubts can benefit by reading the conversation .

Comment: @JackCrawford : Please don’t delete comments. It makes all of the back-and-forth completely unintelligible. You can make a retraction in a new comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not follow that every element has a unique predecessor. For example, consider the [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) $\omega + 1 = \omega \cup \{\omega\}$. Then $\omega$ itself does not have a predecessor. In particular, the set $\{\omega\} \subset \omega + 1$ is not open.

Comment: Is well ordered set countable , if yes then we can prove that every element must have predecessor (except smallest and largest )

Comment: @Shawn No, my example is countable and not every element has a predecessor.

Comment: I am reading a proof from munkres of Theorem :: Every well ordered set X is normal in the order topology .In the proof it is given "let A and B be disjoint closed sets in X and they don't contain smallest element .Then for each $a∈ A$ , there exists a basis element about a disjoint from $B $ , it contains some interval of the form $(x,a]$ ".How do i justify this  ?

Comment: @Shawn doesn't letting x be the smallest element of $A$ work?

Comment: "there exists a basis element about a disjoint from B ; it contains some interval " , there is semicolon not comma .Sorry !

Comment: No taking x be the smallest element does not work since B can be subset of (x,a]

Comment: @Shawn Oh I see, yes this is annoying.You really need to used that A and B are closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100364/discussion-between-shawn-and-levi-ryffel).